# Change att of the video to its corresponding item when you press the enter key

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an application for podcasts and accurate when press the "enter" just change the attribute of the corresponding item of the video, however can not reload the page, just change the video. Anyone know how to do?

javascript:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

    // Load Titles patch Json
    console.log(data.query.results.channel.item);
    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
        return item.title;

    });
    var urls = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
        return item.origLink;

    });
    console.log(titles);
    $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));
    $(".container-list-podcast ul li").each(function (key, value) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<a href="' + urls[key] + '">' + text + '</a>');
    });
    $(".container-list-podcast ul li a").click(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(href);
        $("#myvideo").attr("src", href).get(0).play();
        return false;
    })
    // Load Navigation Only Key
    a = $('.nav_holder li').keynav(function () {
        return window.keyNavigationDisabled;
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf5QU/6/)

Comment: What `.keynav` plugin are you using?

Comment: http://www.firedev.com/jquery.keynav/